# I'm a beginner at python and when I try and run my code, the console does absolutely nothing

Tags: python

I'm trying to make my own version of hangman, but whenever I try to run the code through cmd prompt, it displays absolutely nothing. I'm trying to get it to run the game of hangman after importing a text file called text.txt. Does anybody have any idea why this is happening?

I've tried running the code through pylint to see if that will help me out, but the main thing its kicking back is the fact I'm using camelcase, there's lots of tabs instead of spaces, and that the variable "word" is unused, which it isn't....

```
#imports random and words from words.txt
import random
def main():
    word=newWord()
    gameOn()
    playAgain()

hangman = ['''
      _______
     |      |
     |      
     |      
     |    
 ____|___''', '''
      ________
     |      |
     |      ()
     |      
     |       
     |      
 ____|___''', '''
       _______
     |      |
     |      ()
     |      |
     |       
     |      
 ____|___''', '''
      _______
     |      |
     |      ()
     |      /|
     |       
     |          
 ____|___''', '''
      _______
     |      |
     |      ()
     |      /|/
     |       
     |      
 ____|___''', '''
      _______
     |      |
     
     |      ()
     |      /|/
     |      /
     |      
 ____|___''', '''
      _______
     |      |
     |      ()
     |      /|/
     |      /\
     |      
 ____|___''']

#Generates a new word
def newWord():
    lines = open("text.txt")
    line = lines[0]
    words = line.split()
    word = random.choice(words)

#this is what we use to run the game
def gameOn(word):
    print("Welcome to hangman!")
    print(hangman(lives))
    print(hiddenWord)
    #making the word we have *'d off equal to the length of the word
    hiddenWord = "*" * len(word)
    #We'll need to set 2 arrays, 1 with letters guessed and 1 thats the answer.
    #We'll split these down into individuals chars later
    guessedLetters = []
    guessedWords = []
    guess = False
    #1 attempt for : head, 2 arms, 2 legs, body
    lives = 6

    #the while loop checks if the player has any lives left, which we'll use to check if the player has lost or not
    while not guessed and lives > 0:
        guess = input("Please guess a letter!")
        #if length of guess is 1, it runs the internal loop. if not, it re-runs the while loop
        if len(guess) == 1:
            #loop inside a loop for correct guess. adds the letter into the guessed letters list. new variable for the word allows us to make the word into a list to compare off to
            if guess in word:
                print("That's a correct guess!")
            guessedLetters.append(guess)
            listWord = list(hiddenWord)
            #enumerate works to loop through the line and count automatically
             indices = [x for x, letter in enumerate(word) if letter == guess]
            for index in indicies:
                listWord = guess
            #"".join brings it together
            hiddenWord = "".join(listWord)
            if "*" not in hiddenWord:
                guessed = True
                hiddenWord = word
            #checks if the guess has been entered already
            elif guess in guessedLetters:
                print("You've already guessed that! Try again!")
            #if the guess doesnt fufill the above, it takes a life then adds it to the guessedLetters list
             else:
                print("That's not in the word...")
                lives -= 1
                guessedLetters.append(guess)                
        else:
            print("Not a valid guess, try again!")
            print(hangman(lives))
            print(hiddenWord)
        #Next, to check if the player has won
        if guessed:
            print("Well done! You got it!")
        else:
            print("You lose!")
    
def playAgain():
    while input("Play again? Y/N") == "Y":
        main()
```

Comment: You are only defining functions and are actually not calling `main()` anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You never call `main()`. See [Defining Main Functions in Python](https://realpython.com/python-main-function/). After defining your `main` function, you either need to put in a top-level call to `main()` (probably at the bottom of the file), or put it in a `if __name__ == "__main__":` block.

You've defined `main()` and several other functions, but in order for any function to run in Python, you have to explicitly run it via `function_name()`. In some other languages like C, if you define a function called `main`, it'll automatically run, but that's not quite the case in Python.

Answer (score 0):

You must call the function. At the end of the program, with no indentations, write
`main()` into the program. hope this helped.